# Read SerialDataPort many times

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've an issue with my code, I want to read the serialport thanks to DataReceivedHandler, but i work just once. This serial port is a EnOcean usb key who receive data from an electronic card when i press a button on it. the data send are 24 bytes. First time I press the button it works perfectly fine, I receive the data, but if I press a second time, nothing happen, the DataReceivedHandler don't see anything and don't send me the data.

```
    public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //init serialport comport
        SerialPort comport = (SerialPort)sender;

        // Shortened and error checking removed for brevity...
        int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
        string indata = comport.ReadExisting();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        HandleSerialData(buffer, comport);

    }
```

HandleSerialData works, it doesn't matter in my problem i think, i let the code just in case of.

```
    public void HandleSerialData(byte[] respBuffer, SerialPort comport)
    {
        /*StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(respBuffer.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in respBuffer)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);*/

        string hex = "";
        int n = 0;
        byte[] ID_TIC;
        ID_TIC = new byte[8];

        for (int i = 12 ; i < 15; i++)
        {
            ID_TIC[n] = respBuffer[i];
                n = n++;
        }

        hex = hex + BitConverter.ToString(ID_TIC).Replace("-",string.Empty);

        string hex2 = hex.ToString();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { EnOcean_Label.Content = ID_TIC; }));
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { EnOcean2_Label.Content = ID_TIC; }));

        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User() { NumeroTIC = hex2, NumeroCNT1 = hex2, Date = DateTime.Now });

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { dgSimple.ItemsSource = users; }));

        WriteTest(ID_TIC);


    }
```

Comment: We already told you how to do it correctly in your previous question, you are still getting it drastically wrong.  Calling ReadExisting() *and* Read() makes no sense at all, you'll never get anything from the Read() since ReadExisting already emptied the receive buffer.  And you are still not counting bytes, it is a hard requirement and you cannot ignore the return value of Read().  Ask a team member to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not opening the serialport after sending the bytes (you need to do this by):

```
//Last line of code that sends the hex-code
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) //Assuming you're starting with an open port
```

...And wait for the reply

Or:

```
//Last line of code that sends the hex-code
comPortReadFunction()
```

Your read function should not have any parameters. You do not need to have parameters when you're listening the COM-port

Comment: Okay so, after few test, it happen that my serialport is not connected (like is somehow comport.close(); happened somewhere in my code but it doesn't) after the first telegram

Comment: you didn't include your full code so I can't say anything about that. Show us everything.

Answer (score -2):

Well, i know why is my problem, my serialport is not defined as static, and the garbage collector is killing it everytime is called

Comment: Where is the `WriteTest(ID_TIC)`-function? The `Thread.Sleep` should be after that exact line (if its the one sending out the command)